# Evaluating two epochs - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've tried evaluating an epoch with another epoch using `<` but it always returns true or false, which is wrong. I converted them both to dates, but the same issue happens where its all either true or false based on if I use `<` or `>` Some are should be true and some should be false.

```
auctionHasEnded(auctionEndDate: Date) {
    let date: Date;
    date = new Date();
    return new Date(auctionEndDate) < date;
  }


 <td [ngStyle]="{'width': '55%'}" id="dateReceived" class="tableStyle" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              <span id="endDateTimeLabel" [ngStyle]="{'color':row.auctionEndDateTime  > this.today ? 'red' : 'green' }">
                {{auctionHasEnded(row.auctionEndDateTime)}}</span></td>
          </ng-container>
```

`auctionEndDateTime examples from JSON response: 1576779848, 1577379500, 1578069935, 1577999303`

If I have an epoch, how can I evaluate it? I thought converting it to a date and comparing it to a new Date() would be the way to go, but it doesn't seem to evaluating correctly. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the times you can convert today time to epoch just like that:

```js
this.today = +(new Date()/1000) // divide by 1000 to get seconds
1576779848 < this.today // true
```

Date in JS is by milliseconds as you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: This ```{{1578069935 > this.today}}``` evaluates to false. When I put 
this.today = +(new Date());  in ngOnInit. It should be true

Comment: Just saw that your time is by seconds, so you need to divide by 1000, updated the answer as well